# How do I create one class to use in a different project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have many projects in IOS. Some of them use the same classes (app1, app2 and app3 use the same classes as `class1.m` and `class2.m`).
Is there any way to collect these apps in one app (multi task) or use these classes for only one time for all apps?

Comment: Read about static libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can compile your classes into a static library and add it to your future projects as dependency.

[This](http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial) is a good tutorial for it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom pod spec repo and host your shared classes that way.  You could group them all together and have one big `Yahia` pod, otherwise, you could segment it and pull in just what you need:

https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html